# Condition based spool generation in Oracle SQL script

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-scripts

I have a scenario where we generate spool based on condition.

The spool should generate only if user types y.

```
column col noprint new_value elcm_script
select decode(lower('&gen'),'y','C:\ELCM.SQL','n', 'null') col from dual;

SPOOL c:\ELCM_DETAILS.SPL 
@&elcm_script
spool off
```

In the above it will generate spool file even if user type n like error reading file.. How to stop generating the spool if n.or how to remove spool which is generated/

Comment: You could put the SPOOL command inside the script ELCM.SQL?

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't want to run the script at all; it's not just that you want to run it but not spool the output to a file?

Comment: I don't want to generate a spool unless user types 'y'.

Comment: That didn't really answer my question, but I'll assume you don't want to run the script, based on the current decode. Is this being run through SQL*Plus?

Comment: It is run through sql developer

Comment: Yes Alex I dont want the script to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can put this controlling section into its own script, e.g. `elcm_ctl.sql`, you could make that:

```
accept run_it char format a1 prompt "Run the script?"

set termout off

whenever sqlerror exit success rollback
exec if upper(nvl('&run_it', 'N')) != 'Y' then raise no_data_needed; end if;
whenever sqlerror continue

spool c:\elcm.sql
select 'select sysdate from dual;' from dual;
spool off

set termout on

spool c:\elcm_details.spl
@c:\elcm.sql
spool off
```

The [`accept` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve005.htm) is a bit neater than relying on substitution prompts, in my opinion, and is somewhat self-documenting. This prompts the user with the specified string, rather than just `'gen'`. (In SQL*Plus you can extend this and force the user to put in a single character, re-prompting if they put in anything longer; and default to 'N' if they just press return without entering anything. But SQL Developer only supports a subset of the functionality).

Then a small anonymous block throws an exception - doesn't really matter which one - if the entered variable value is not `'y'` or `'Y'`. While it's doing that I've [`set termout off`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2683459) so you don't see the actual exception. And I've used [`whenever sqlerror`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm) to make the script exit when that exception is raised, so whatever comes later is not run. That is everything else in the control script, not just the next query, but you could have several sub-scripts if you needed to be more flexible.

But in SQL Developer, `termout` only works as expected when you run via `@`. If you run the contents of `elcm_ctl.sql` directly from the SQL Worksheet you'll see the exception being raised, which is a bit ugly. So instead save that control script and in an empty worksheet just do:

```
@c:\elcm_ctl.sql
```

Execute that worksheet as a script and it will prompt you; if you enter `'Y'` you'll see the output of the script in the script output window (unless you leave `set termout off` in the control script), and it will create the spool file. If you enter anything else then it won't run the `elcm.sql` file, won't show anything in the script output window, and won't create a spool file.

Comment: Perfect Alex..I have one more question. I am generating that C:\ELCM.SQL in my script.Can i stop that as well. ?

Comment: You don't need the `decode` if that's what you mean? What I showed is the complete script I was running to verify this.

Comment: In my script . I generate t C:\ELCM.SQL like this.

SPOOL c:\ELCM.SQL
select 'select sysdate from dual; from dual;
spool off
column col noprint new_value elcm_script
select decode(lower('&gen'),'y','C:\ELCM.SQL','n', 'null') col from dual;

SPOOL c:\ELCM_DETAILS.SPL 
@&elcm_script
spool off

I dont want .sql to generate if user types n

Comment: If you generate it after the `exec` check then it will be skipped too, yes.

Comment: u mean to say whenever sqlerror exit success rollback
set termout off
exec if upper(nvl('&run_it', 'N')) != 'Y' then
 "ALL MY .SQL genreation statements 
raise no_data_needed; end if;
set termout on
whenever sqlerror continue

spool c:\elcm_details.spl
@c:\elcm.sql
spool off

..Is that correct?

Comment: @user3737084 - not 100% sure I follow, but I've added what I think you mean, creating the script you run from within the control script.