# Problems while spooling data from Oracle. It spools elapsed time instead of spooling result of sql query into output file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am trying to make a cron job that runs once a day. On invoking the shell script, it calls a Sql file. Which in turn Spools data into a file. This file is Picked by Shell Script and then mailed accordingly. Problem is when I try to spool data , it is writing elapsed time instead of writing actual result of query to the output file.

Here is the sql file I am using.

```
set define off
set numformat 99999999999999999999999999
set markup html on
set serveroutput on
set head on
set pages 3000
set echo off 

DECLARE
total integer :=0;
total = select count(*) from t_c_table1 vt, t_c_table2 ti WHERE vt.f_item_id = ti.f_item_id (+) AND (f_update_date < sysdate - 30)order by F_INSERT_DATE desc; 

IF total > 0 then 

spool /home/output.csv
select f_name, count (*) from t_c_table1 where F_INSERT_DATE < sysdate-100 group by f_item_provider_id;
spool off

END IF
```

I get output like Elapsed: 00:00:00.506 in the spooled csv file.

Where am i going wrong? 
Please Help. 
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: `spool` is a sqlplus command. You can't use that inside a SQL statement or a PL/SQL block

Comment: So where should i use spool? Inside shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted is wrong, it won't even compile in Oracle so I'm surprised that you got *anything* at all.

As there's no `SET TIMING ON`, I'm not sure what produced the elapsed time line in the spooled file. Maybe it is some old, previously created CSV file you're looking at?

Apart from the fact that `SPOOL` is a SQL*Plus command (so you can't invoke it in a PL/SQL procedure), the way you calculated the TOTAL variable's value is wrong - it should be part of the `SELECT ... INTO` statement.

```
SQL> declare
  2    total integer := 0;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*)
  5      into total
  6      from dept;
  7
  8    if total > 0 then
  9       spool test.csv
 10       select * from dept;
 11       spool off;
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /
     spool test.csv
           *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TEST" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;


SQL>
```

If you want to spool data conditionally, you'll have to use the `UTL_FILE` package.

Or, you could do it "interactively" so that SQL*Plus asks you whether you want to spool data or not, as Alex Poole described in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446924/condition-based-spool-generation-in-oracle-sql-script).